# Десятичная точка при расчёте ведёт себя неправильно. В чём моя ошибка?

Tags: c#, ооп

*Я пока абсолютный ноль в C#.*

При вводе в `number1` числа > 1 десятичная точка либо исчезает, либо находится не в том месте.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace uroki1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string quit = "none";
            
            do
            {
                double rubusd = 0.013198;
                double rubeur = 0.011509;
                double usdrub = 75.77;
                double usdeur = 0.8765;
                double eurrub = 86.89;
                double eurusd = 1.14;
                double number1;
                double course=0;
                    
                // валюта:
                string choice1 = "none";
                string choice2 = "none";
                // результат
                double result = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("выберите валюту 1\nсуществующие валюты:rub, eur, usd");

                do
                {
                    Console.Write("Введите название валюты: ");
                    choice1 = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (choice1 != "rub" && choice1 != "eur" && choice1 != "usd")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("!!Ошибка!!, неправильное значение");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("вы выбрали " + choice1 + " для числа 1");

                    }
                } while (choice1 != "rub" && choice1 != "eur" && choice1 != "usd");

                //------------------------------------------------------------//
                do
                {
                    Console.Write("Введите название валюты: ");
                    choice2 = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (choice2 != "rub" && choice2 != "eur" && choice2 != "usd")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("!!Ошибка!!, неправильное значение");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("вы выбрали " + choice2 + " для числа 2");
                    }
                } while (choice1 != "rub" && choice1 != "eur" && choice1 != "usd");

                Console.WriteLine("введите сумму " + choice1);
                number1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                double number = number1;
                if (choice1 == choice2) { Console.WriteLine("столько же..."); }
                else
                {
                    if (choice1 == "rub" && choice2 == "usd") { course = number1 * rubusd; }
                    if (choice1 == "rub" && choice2 == "eur") { course = number1 * rubeur; }

                    if (choice1 == "eur" && choice2 == "rub") {course = number1 * eurrub; }
                    if (choice1 == "eur" && choice2 == "usd") { course = number1 * eurusd; }

                    if (choice1 == "usd" && choice2 == "rub") { course = number1 * usdrub; }
                    if (choice1 == "usd" && choice2 == "eur") { course = number1 * usdeur; }
                }

                result = number1 * course;

                Console.WriteLine(number + choice1 + " = " + Math.Round(result, 2) + choice2);
                Console.WriteLine("Введите q для повтора. Для выхода введите что-угодно");
                quit = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (quit == "q");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) удалите все лишнее из своего кода, оставьте только тот код, в клотором ошибка. Чтобы можно было скопировать, запустить и увидеть ошибку, без каких либо дополнительных телодвижений 2) Ясно опишите ошибку. Что вы ожидаете на выходе программы получить и что получаете и почему ваше ожидаемое - правильное, а получаемое - не правильное. Чтобы не надо было гадать, скопировал ваш код, запустил и сразу понял ваше проблему. Пока что ничего не понаятно, ни проблема, ни код, ничего.

Comment: "При вводе в number1 числа" - Нам плохо видно, что и как Вы вводите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя есть переменная course, в которую ты записываешь введенное пользователем число (денежная сумма) (`number1`) умноженное на коэффициент (соотношение валют). Это уже является деньгами в другой валюте, а ты зачем-то выполняешь вот эту команду (повторно что-то вычисляя):

```
result = number1 * course;
```

`Course` уже является готовым результатом.

Предположу, что ты хотел сделать вот так:

```
if (choice1 == choice2) { Console.WriteLine("столько же..."); }
else
{
    if (choice1 == "rub" && choice2 == "usd") { course = rubusd; }
    if (choice1 == "rub" && choice2 == "eur") { course = rubeur; }
    if (choice1 == "eur" && choice2 == "rub") { course = eurrub; }
    if (choice1 == "eur" && choice2 == "usd") { course = eurusd; }
    if (choice1 == "usd" && choice2 == "rub") { course = usdrub; }
    if (choice1 == "usd" && choice2 == "eur") { course = usdeur; }
}

result = number1 * course;
```